# MySQL index for constant values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

How looks like an optimal MySQL index for this query:

```
select a,b,c from t where a=1 and b=2 order by c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimal index is:  `t(a, b, c)` or `t(b, a, c)`.

The first two columns of the index will be used for the `where` clause.  The third column can then be used for the `order by`.